# Spring Security Social Login,Storing the social user data in database

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, mybatis, spring-social

I created social login for facebook,linkedin and google.The login process is working fine but I want to store the user data such as emailId,social provider in my database,in which I am facing problem.This is an spring-Mybatis project.

my **spring_social_security.xml** class contain all the mapping

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

<bean id="socialAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationProvider">
    <constructor-arg ref="inMemoryUsersConnectionRepository"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="socialUserDetailService"/>
</bean>
```

```
<!-- social login filter which is a pre authentication filter and works for /auth service url -->
<bean id="socialAuthenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationFilter">
    <constructor-arg name="authManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <constructor-arg name="userIdSource" ref="userIdSource"/>
    <constructor-arg name="usersConnectionRepository" ref="inMemoryUsersConnectionRepository"/>
    <constructor-arg name="authServiceLocator" ref="appSocialAuthenticationServiceRegistry"/>
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successHandler"/>
</bean>

 <!-- inmemory connection repository which holds connection repository per local user -->
<bean id="inMemoryUsersConnectionRepository"
      class="org.springframework.social.connect.mem.InMemoryUsersConnectionRepository">
    <constructor-arg name="connectionFactoryLocator" ref="appSocialAuthenticationServiceRegistry"/>
    <property name="connectionSignUp" ref="connectionSignUp"/>
</bean>

<!-- service registry will holds connection factory of each social provider -->
<bean id="appSocialAuthenticationServiceRegistry"
      class="com.technoshinelabs.ulearn.registry.AppSocialAuthenticationServiceRegistry">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <ref bean="facebookAuthenticationService"/>
            <ref bean="linkedInAuthenticationService"/>
            <ref bean="googleAuthenticationService"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="facebookAuthenticationService"
      class="org.springframework.social.facebook.security.FacebookAuthenticationService">
    <constructor-arg name="apiKey" value="${facebook.api.key}"/>
    <constructor-arg name="appSecret" value="${facebook.api.secret}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="linkedInAuthenticationService"
      class="org.springframework.social.linkedin.security.LinkedInAuthenticationService">
    <constructor-arg name="apiKey" value="${linkedin.api.key}"/>
    <constructor-arg name="appSecret" value="${linkedin.api.secret}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="googleAuthenticationService"
      class="org.springframework.social.google.security.GoogleAuthenticationService">
    <constructor-arg name="apiKey" value="${google.api.key}"/>
    <constructor-arg name="appSecret" value="${google.api.secret}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="userIdSource" class="org.springframework.social.security.AuthenticationNameUserIdSource"/>

<!-- If no local user is associated to a social connection then connection sign up will create a new local user and map it to social user -->
<bean id="connectionSignUp" class="com.technoshinelabs.ulearn.registry.AppConnectionSignUp"/>
```

**AppConnectionSignUp.java**class contains execute() which does the execution of the app.

```
public class AppConnectionSignUp implements ConnectionSignUp {

@Override
public String execute(final Connection<?> connection) {
    SignUpForm userDetails = toUserRegistrationObject(connection.getKey().getProviderUserId(),
            SecurityUtil.toSocialProvider(connection.getKey().getProviderId()), connection.fetchUserProfile());

    try {
        HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes())
                .getRequest();

        return user.getUsername();
    } catch (UserAlreadyExistAuthenticationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

}

private SignUpForm toUserRegistrationObject(final String userId, final SocialProvider socialProvider,
        final UserProfile userProfile) {
    return SignUpForm.getBuilder().addUserId(userId).addFirstName(userProfile.getFirstName())
            .addEmail(userProfile.getEmail()).addPassword(userProfile.getName()).addSocialProvider(socialProvider)
            .build();
}
```

}

AppAuthenticationEntryPoint.java

```
public class AppAuthenticationEntryPoint extends LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint {

private final RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();


/**
 * @param loginFormUrl URL where the login page can be found. Should either be
 *                     relative to the web-app context path (include a leading {@code /}) or an absolute
 *                     URL.
 */
public AppAuthenticationEntryPoint(final String loginFormUrl) {
    super(loginFormUrl);
}

/**
 * Performs the redirect (or forward) to the login form URL.
 */
public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                     AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {

    // redirect to login page. Use https if forceHttps true
    String redirectUrl = buildRedirectUrlToLoginPage(request, response, authException);
    System.out.println("redirect Url: "+ redirectUrl);

    redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, redirectUrl);
}
```

}

Comment: I believe each of your linkedin, facebook, etc methods will have an entry-point, where you can check if user is logged in or token is valid(whichever mechanism is present in the entry-point), at that location you can call your methods for saving in DB.

Comment: You need to clarify you question. It is not clear what you are asking

Comment: yes I have a class called AppAuthenticationEntryPoint.java  @WeareBorg